# Multiple Google Analytics Properties with WordPress Borlabs Cookies

Tags: wordpress, cookies, google-analytics

I am using the WordPress plugin [Borlabs Cookie](https://borlabs.io/borlabs-cookie/) to manage Google Analytics. It delivers the appropriate JavaScript-code which transfers the data to Google if the user agrees. Therefore you have to enter the Tracking ID (usually the UA-number) within the properties of Borlabs Cookie.

The question is: how can I connect my website to *more than one* Google Analytics property? I need this to migrate to the new Google Analytics Version 4. They recommend using the old version parallel to the new one for a while.

If you manage your code by yourself you simply have to double some lines of code with the old UA- and the new G-number like this:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-…"></script>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-…"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-…', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
  gtag('config', 'G-…', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
</script>
```

Is there a way to do the same with the Borlabs Cookie plugin? Adding another cookie is not the right way, I guess, because the same cookie is used for both properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the WordPress plugin Borlabs Cookie, tracking to multiple properties of Google Analytics is quite easy (and I wonder why I did not find the solution by myself but had to ask the Borlabs support).

Anyway, go to the plugin settings on the Cookies tab and edit the Google Analytics cookie. Within the HTML & JavaScript section substitute the Opt-in Code with something like:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-X');
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

For the details of this code look at [Michele Pisani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64402323/13520223).

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/basic-tag?technology=gtagjs) about '**How to tag for both Universal Analytics and Google Analytics 4 properties**' (if you are already using gtag) said:

> If you already use gtag.js for your UA property, you can either
>
> 1. add one line to your existing gtag.js page snippet as explained below,
>    or
> 2. use Connected Site Tags to add your GA4 Measurement ID without
>    changing the code on your page.
>
> To change your code, add the following config command to your existing
> gtag.js snippet:
>
> `gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');`
>
> where G-XXXXXXXXXX is the Measurement ID for a GA4 data stream.
>
> For example, here is the complete gtag.js snippet you would use to
> collect data for a UA property with an ID of 'UA-XXXXXX-13' and a GA4
> data stream ID of 'G-XXXXXXXXXX'.

Example:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-13"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-13');
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

So you **don't need** to add this part:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-…"></script>
```

About you question, you don't need to manage IP anonymization in GA4 since, in GA4 properties, IP addresses are automatically anonymized: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/basic-tag?technology=gtagjs#ip_anonymization

Comment: Your hints are very helpful in general – thanks for that. Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my actual question, how to configure that with the WordPress Plugin "Borlabs Cookies". I opened a ticket at Borlabs and will share their answer here.

Comment: Great thanks, if the question actually goes beyond the anonymization of the IP I would say that the right way is precisely to contact them, since GA4 is a recent novelty, they will still have to organize for its management.